# Media server crashes after random time: AudioFlinger server died

Tags: android, rtsp, wowza

I am building a RTSP video stream app on Android with WOWZA media streaming server. All works fine on S4 MINI, but some devices (Acer Z500) get a random disconnect after some time..

I use Libstream library to connect to the WOWZA server.
link: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

The same problem can be found here:
[Android AudioFlinger server died | media server died](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097512/android-audioflinger-server-died-media-server-died)

But nowhere on the internet I can find a good solution, as most people get 'never' connected, my application works for 30-3000 seconds before the error pops up.

here is the callstack:

```
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2222/com.example.afterparty.app W/AudioSystem﹕  AudioFlinger server died!<br>
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2222/com.example.afterparty.app W/IMediaDeathNotifier﹕ media server died
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2222/com.example.afterparty.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (100, 0)
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2222/com.example.afterparty.app W/Camera﹕ Camera server died!
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2222/com.example.afterparty.app W/AudioSystem﹕ AudioPolicyService server died!
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2222/com.example.afterparty.app W/Camera﹕ ICamera died
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2048/com.example.afterparty.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (100,0)
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2048/com.example.afterparty.app D/VideoView﹕ Error: 100,0
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2048/com.example.afterparty.app E/FragmentVideoHud﹕ Error! Biatch: 100
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2048/com.example.afterparty.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2048/com.example.afterparty.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6298288)
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2129/com.example.afterparty.app E/Camera﹕ Error 100
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2129/com.example.afterparty.app E/VideoStream﹕ Media server died !
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2137/com.example.afterparty.app D/H264Packetizer﹕ H264 packetizer stopped !
07-03 21:08:59.951    2048-2129/com.example.afterparty.app D/VideoStream﹕ Locking camera
```

Comment: Your stackoverflow link got an answer - just write RTSP proxy server and handle rtp streaming issues there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8652734/7125023